# Javascript Logical Operator Confusion

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logical-operators

I have a complete working program, but I am very confused about the logic in a couple of my conditional statements after I fiddled with them in an attempt to get the program to do what I want.

```
    while (col < 5 || 20 < col || Number.isInteger(col)) {
        col = prompt("Columns (Int between 5 and 20): ","10");
        console.log("col " + col);
    }
    while (row < 5 || 20 < row || Number.isInteger(row)) {
        row = prompt("Rows (Int between 5 and 20): ","10");
        console.log("row " + row);
    }

    if (row>col) {size = 400/col;console.log("colmore");}
    else if (col>row) {size = 400/row;console.log("rowmore");}
    else {size = 400/col;console.log("same");}
    console.log("size " + size);
```

Now my program prompts for the number of Columns and then Rows. For example, I'll put in 20 for columns, and 5 for rows - columns are obviously more than rows then. So this happens:

```
col 20
row 5
colmore
size 20
```

Obviously that's what I want it to do, but I'm getting hung up because that first condition

```
if (row>col)
```

*should* mean if rows are more than columns, and the program should continue to the next statement... or am I just completely losing my mind...?

Comment: `prompt` returns strings, and the _string_ `"20"` is indeed less than the _string_ `"5"`; cast your `row` and `col` to integers to get the desired behavior

Comment: note that this is a great example of why debugging with `console.log` can lead to a lot more confusion than debugging with [the actual debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger)

Comment: If you got row and column from string input then you're performing stringA > stringB, use parseInt() to treat as integers.  This behaviour might be different for the earlier if statements since there the strings were coerced to integers.

Comment: I knew it was going to be some simple mess-up. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
while (col < 5 || col > 20 || !Number.isInteger(col)) {
    col = Number(prompt("Columns (Int between 5 and 20): ","10"));
    console.log("col " + col);
}

while (row < 5 || row > 20 || !Number.isInteger(row)) {
    row = Number(prompt("Rows (Int between 5 and 20): ","10"));
    console.log("row " + row);
}
```

Changes:

- Convert the string input to a number so we wrap the prompt response in a Number() call; this casts the string to a number returning either a number or NaN if it isn't a number
- Stay in the while loop if it is NOT an integer (you had if it is an integer); notice the !
- Switch the second condition in the while so it reads more naturally (perhaps a matter of taste but I find it easier to read col < 5 or col > 20 than col < 5 or 20 < col)

Answer (score 0):

With if (row>col) you are saying if rows number(int) is greater than col number(int) then run this code

```
size = 400/col;console.log("colmore");
```

and skip this code

```
else if (col>row) {size = 400/row;console.log("rowmore");}
else {size = 400/col;console.log("same");}
```

and then run this code

```
console.log("size " + size);
```

I have edited your code and broken down the steps to help you.

```
//declare variable as prompt first
var col = prompt("Columns (Int between 5 and 20): ","10");
/* ** continue to display prompt if user enters a number below 5 or a number above 20 or a character which is not a number ** */
while (col < 5 || col < 20 || isNaN(col)) {
  col = prompt("Columns (Int between 5 and 20): ","10");
  console.log("col " + col);
}
// notice the use of isNaN(row) which is checking the col variable

//declare variable as prompt first
var row = prompt("Rows (Int between 5 and 20): ","10");
/* ** continue to display prompt if user enters a number below 5 or a number above 20 or a character which is not a number ** */
while (row < 5 || row < 20 || isNaN(row)) {
  row = prompt("Rows (Int between 5 and 20): ","10");
  console.log("row " + row);
}
// notice the use of isNaN(row) which is checking the row variable

//First check if row is greated than col
if (row > col) {
  size = 400/col;console.log("More Rows " + row + "rows and " + col + "cols");//if true run this code
}
//if row is not greater than col then check if col is greater than row
else if (col > row) {
  size = 400/row;console.log("More Cols " + col + "cols" + row + "rows and ");//if true then run this code
}
//else row and col must be equal
else {
  size = 400/col;console.log("same amount");//so run this code run this code
}
//end if statement and move on with code
console.log("size " + size);
```

Your definately on the right track.
Would recommend using isNaN() method.